# Dynamically adding Sections to UITableView, then dynamically adding sub cells to specific section.

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, uitableview

I'm new to programming, so my apologies for not used proper terminology.

Trying to create a tableview where users can create new sections in the tableview and then dynamically add subcells to a specific section (section headers will contain an "add" button to add these cells. Something like a To-Do-List function with subItems.

Would i use a "sender" or "tag" for the buttons in the sections, so that they do not add cells to other sections. OR how does,(in layman terms) the button know that cells are to be added only to that section.

I've been researching and everything i've found are for predefined arrays.So if anyone can point me in the right direction, it will be very much appreciated.

Comment: tags for your buttons should work just fine.  On click check the tag, add to the correct section.

Comment: P.S. hooray for new programmers!

Comment: @lostintranslation, thanks gonna try that out now!

Answer (score 1):

```
#pragma mark - Tableview Delegate



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{
//number of section to add in tableview
    return 1;

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

{

    return //number of row you want to add in particular section ;

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

    NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %ld",(long)indexPath.row];



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];



    cell = nil;



    if (cell == nil)

    {

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];







        cell.textLabel.text = //set data to cell which you want ;



        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];





    }



    return cell;

}



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;

{
//perform action after clicking on particular cell of tableview 


}
```